# Caliburn Can{Action} not getting updated on Refresh()

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn, action

```
    public void AddProfile()
    {
        //Add conventions for DX Components.
        Profile newProfile = new Profile()
        {
            Description = "New Profile",
            DisplayOrder = decimal.MaxValue,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDefault = false,
            IsSelected = true,
            ProfileId = 0
        };
        EditProfileViewModel profile = new EditProfileViewModel(true) { Profile = newProfile };


        if (windowManager.ShowDialog(profile,null ) ?? false) // ?? means (coallesce so if null use false value) the line means, if dialog returns true...
        {
            Profiles.Add(profile.Profile);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(string.Empty);
        }

    }
```

The code for the can add buttons is like this.

```
    public bool CanAddAllToProfile
    {
        get
        {
            var p = Profiles.Where(x => x.IsSelected).FirstOrDefault();
            if (p == null)
                return false;
            if (AvailableModules.Count() == 0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void AddAllToProfile()
    {
        var p = Profiles.Where(x => x.IsSelected).FirstOrDefault();
        if (p == null)
            return;
        foreach (var m in AvailableModules)
            p.Modules.Add(m);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(string.Empty);
    }
```

The CanAddAllToProfile get does not get executed if I write the code like this.

if I do a NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanAddAllToProfile) it works

I also tried Refresh();

I am inheriting the viewmodel from Screen  any ideas  I have a bunch of other CanExecuteBindings that need to be executed.  Obviously this can be worked around but I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: How are you wiring this up in XAML? Does the AddAllToProfile() get hit when you click the button?

Comment: Is this Caliburn Micro or the full Caliburn?

Comment: full caliburn and yea it gets hit when I click the button. I am just wiring it up using x:name="AddAllToProfile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just gave the answer in your question:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanAddAllToProfile);
```

That is the appropriate way to tell the binding infrastructure that it should call `CanAddAllToProfile` and update anything that is binding to that property (such as the button named `AddAllToProfile`). So if it works, why are you not doing that?